# Compare hexadecimal character array

Tags: c

I have 2 character arrays:

`unsigned char test_1[2] and unsigned char test_2[2]`

Both of them have hex value in it. So if I do for loop like:

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(test_1); i++)
     printf("%02x\n", test_1[i])

and 

for (i=0; i<sizeof(test_2); i++)
     printf("%02x\n", test_2[i])
```

It will print something like:

```
2e
50

and 

a1
3e
```

My question is, how do I compare these two char arrays? I have numerous character arrays like `test_3, test_4, ...., test_n` to be compared with `test_1`.

I used `strcmp()` and it failed because they are not a string.

****** update *******

code logic:

```
while(memcmp(test_1, test_n,2) != 0){

     // grab the next test_n char array (test_2, test_3, ....)
     // set test_n to have same value as the next test_n
}
printf("Stop the search, I found it!"\n);
```

Comment: Look at `memcmp()`.

Comment: @chux it didn't work. I tried it and it didn't stop at `test_5`. I intentionally fill `test_5` exactly the same with `test_1`.

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a clear explanation of what was tried nor of the result versus expected results.

Comment: @chux `test_1[0] and test_1[1]` values are 2e and g7. This is also the same as test_5[0] and test_5[1] because I want my loop to say 'Hey stop! I found the one'. However, what just happened was it keep comparing with test_6, test_7, ....

Comment: @ThomasWest: memcmp() should work if your intention is just comparision. Check if you are correctly using memcmp() - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcmp.htm

Comment: @ThomasWest: It is nothing to do with memcmp(). Looks like your logic is wrong somewhere. Share your code.

Comment: @MayurK sure, there you go.

Comment: Not memcpy() . You should use memcmp().

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

If when you do `printf("%02x\n", test_1[i])` you get print-outs like '`g7`', '`t7`' or '`x1`' then you have some problems... (hint: those are not valid hex values)

Now, if you have a lot of those arrays to compare (test_2, test_3, test_4...) then maybe you should use instead a 2D array. When test[1] would be the same as your test_1, test[2] would be the same as your test_2...etc... (actually, you'll probably want to start at test[0], but at least I hope you understand what I am trying to say).

If you have something like that, and you know all of those arrays are of length 2, then you'll be able to do something like:

```
int i;
for(i=2; i<num_arrays; i++) {
  if(!memcmp(test[1], test[i], 2) {
    printf("Array test_%d is equal to test_1\n", i);
  } else {
    printf("Array test_%d is different from test_1\n", i);
  }
}
```

If you do not use a 2D array, then you are pretty much stuck doing it more "by hand":

```
if (!memcmp(test_1, test_2, 2) {
  printf("test_2 is the same\n");
}
if (!memcmp(test_1, test_3, 2) {
  printf("test_3 is the same\n");
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Sorry. It was a bad example. My code showed like "2e a1 3e". My examples were too random.

Comment: Hope you understand how to use the 2D arrays, I think that's the main thing you are missing...

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you sliding_compare.

Anyway, both of them consist of single character sequences.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Btw, test_1[0] contains "2e" and test_1[1] contains "g7"

Comment: "2e" or "g7" seems like two characters but if using wide_char(wchar_t), "2e" seems a single character. <br/>What I say is 'using wide character sliding comapring". <br/>